# Python API Calling Random.org

Tags: python, json, api, random, request

So I am new to APIs but I'm trying to get more practice with them. I am getting connection okay (200) but whenever I try to print the results I receive this error:

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":null},"id":null}

Here's my code, with the api key redacted:

```
    url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke'

    data = {'jsonrpc':'2.0','method':'generateIntegers','params': {'apiKey':'mykeygoeshere','n':10,'min':1,'max':10,'replacement':'true','base':10},'id':24565}

    response = requests.get(url,data)

    print(response.text)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you look at [their own implementation](https://github.com/RandomOrg/JSON-RPC-Python/blob/907a07fe0569a5581f34671703b9c5215316273d/rdoclient/rdoclient.py#L1502), you can see that they're using a `POST`, not a `GET`, and are first running the `data` parameter through `json.dumps()` first. They're also setting the headers, which you probably should be doing as well. However I'm not certain that their code is up-to-date - it is 5 years old. Still, since you want to learn more about APIs, that should be quite helpful if you want to learn how their own API is correctly used.

Comment: Thanks, your comment got it working, just had to change request type and call json.dumps(data)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import requests
    import json

    url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke'

    data = {'jsonrpc':'2.0','method':'generateIntegers','params': {'apiKey':'mykey','n':10,'min':1,'max':10,'replacement':'true','base':10},'id':24565}

    params = json.dumps(data)

    response = requests.post(url,params)

    print(response.text)
```

Comment: This does not work with the current version of the API

Answer (score 0):

This Code Works in Version 2

```py
import requests
import json

raw_data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "generateIntegers",
    "params": {
        "apiKey": "your-api-key",
        "n": 6,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 6,
        "replacement": True
    },
    'id':1
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Content-Length': '200', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

data=json.dumps(raw_data)

response = requests.post(
    url='https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke',
    data=data,
    headers=headers
    )

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

So for random.org you have to make a post request to the url

`https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke`

with data which is stored in the variable raw_data but first you should convert the dictionary object to json format this can be done using the line

```py
data=json.dumps(raw_data)
```

and headers variable stores the format of the POST request

The request is done using the requests module post method

and then we get response in json format which is converted to printable format by

```
print(response.text)
```

be sure to store your api_key in the `raw_data` variable